# hitTest an array with the same array AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I got an little question.

I want that my array will collide so they will stand in a row. (Like in Age of War)
So like

```
if (array[1].hitTestObject(array[0])) array[1].x --;
```

But i want this with array[2] hittest array[1] to...

I hope someone could help me out with this..

greetings Justin Bieshaar

Comment: why don't you use a `for` loop?

Comment: I did , but i dont get it how to make an function that will collide all the parts of the array like:

if the array[1] hittests array[2] , and array[2] hittests array [3] and array[3] hittests array[4] etc

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

I am creating a kinda side scrolling tower defence game.

and i fixed it this way:

```
for (var i:int = eL; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if(enemy[i].x - enemy[i - 1].x < 60){
                        enemy[i].speed = enemy[0].speed;
                    }
                }
            }
```

thanks for the help anyways :)